# RabbitMq .net core client to handle multiple messages in parallel (not one by one)

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq

Let's say I have one publisher and 2 consumers.
Each consumer should consume 5 messages at a time (in parallel).

(one exchange, bound to one queue, direct mode)

- Publisher produces messages (1,2,3,...14,15)
- Consumer A consumes (1,3,5,7,9)
- Consumer B consumes (2,4,6,8,10)
- Consumer A finished processing message 1 and receives message 11
- ... etc

How can I achieve this behaviour?
I realized, that the consumer.Receive event is only fired when the previous message has been processed.

When reading the rabbitmq docs, this seemed exactly what I need:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html

but obviously that setting has no impact on the above mentioned behaviour (messages are still processed serially).

Any ideas?

Comment: have you looked at MassTransit? https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/understand/under-the-hood.html#faq

Comment: MassTransit is the perfect option for people who want to hide behind a library without having to learn the underlying technology. It's also an anti-pattern since it forces all producers and consumers to not only use dotnet, but do ALL communication in MassTransit as well. So if you really want your entire architecture to be glued to a specific language and a specific library, go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> setting prefetch, messages are still processed serially

Because [per-channel messages are be processed serially](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#consumer-callbacks-and-ordering). So you have two options:

1. consume on a single channel and spawn multiple task thread to handle the message.
2. open multiple consumer channel, and process message in that channel thread.

Comment: I went for option 1 using by using creating a LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8